# python adding 'none' to the end of function being printed?

Tags: python

```
xsize = int(input('square hash dimension: '))
def square():
    i=0
    while i < xsize:
        x = '#'*xsize  
        print(x)       
        i+=1

print(square())
```

// trying to write a couple lines to recreate the dimensions input to make a square out of hashes, but the result when -say, 2 is input as 'xsize':
(imgur link)
[output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwyWO.png)

not sure why 'none' is being added, but i am quite new to programming on the whole :P
ty in advance!

Comment: you aren't returning anything from the function, so when you call `print(function())` if the function doesn't have anything to return it returns None and you print that.

Comment: you don't return anything

Comment: More specifically, python is implicitly returning `None` for you.

Comment: how should i write the return in?

Comment: python functions return none by default if you don't return anything explicitly

Comment: you don't _want_ to return anything. just call `square()`. Don't print return value, useless.